# pycharm wont read a txt file on my macbook?

Tags: python

I have a code that needs to sort race times from a text file, this is what I have so far,

```
def get_sec(time_str):
h, m = time_str.split(':')
return int(h) * 3600 + int(m) * 60

with open("Race_Results_Sample.txt", "r")as myList:
    myList = myList.read()
    myList = [l.split(",") for l in myList.splitlines()]
    myList = sorted(myList, key=lambda kv: kv[1])
for line in myList:
    num, last, org, time = line
    place = []
    place.append(time)
    placenum = enumerate(sorted(place))
    print(place, placenum)
for rank, value in enumerate(sorted(place)):
    print(rank, value)
for line in myList:
    num, last, org, time = line
    new_time = get_sec(time)
    mile = round((((new_time/ 3.10686)/60)/60), 3)
    mile = str(mile)
    print ('{:<20s}{:<5s}{:<5s}{:<7s}{:<10s}'.format(last, num, org, 
    time, mile))
```

and when trying to get the code to run, I get the following message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File 
"/Users/jess/Library/Preferences/PyCharmEdu4.0/scratches/scratch.py", 
line 5, in <module>
with open("Race_Results_Sample.txt", "r")as myList:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Race_Results_Sample.txt'
```

what is going on to where it can't read the text file? I have the text file on my desktop.

Comment: You have the file on your desktop. Is your script running in your desktop folder? Print `os.getcwd()`.

Comment: Pycharm's scratch files aren't stored in the same directory as your project. Either move the file to `/Users/jess/Library/Preferences/PyCharmEdu4.0/scratches/` or move your code into a non-scratch file in your project. Additionally you can also use the absolute path to the file which always works.

Comment: I moved my code into a non-scratch file and I was still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Your file is being run from `"/Users/jess/Library/Preferences/PyCharmEdu4.0/scratches/scratch.py"` but you say the file is on your desktop. You will need to pass an [absolute reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/absolute-relative-pathnames-unix/) to the Desktop file.

I suggest moving the file to `"/Users/jess/Library/Preferences/PyCharmEdu4.0/scratches/`. Then you can find it with the relative reference you are using in your script i.e.

`with open("Race_Results_Sample.txt", "r")as myList:`

You should also make sure that you execute the script from that directory.

Comment: That's where the script is located, but the working directory isn't necessarily the same as the directory the script is in.

Comment: so i changed my code to a python file instead of a scratch file, and i was still getting the same error

Comment: I suggest changing the code back to match your post. Next, move the file `Race_Results_Sample.txt` to the folder `/Users/jess/Library/Preferences/PyCharmEdu4.0/scratches/`. After this, run the script via Terminal. First run `cd /Users/jess/Library/Preferences/PyCharmEdu4.0/scratches/`. Next run, `python -m scratch`. Until you feel more confident with Python, I recommend using a simple text editor (like Atom or Sublime) and the shell to do your programming. The book/website *Learn Python the Hard Way* talks about this in chapter 0. Pycharm is probably overkill for this project.

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot find on my MacBook, where to move the file. I have looked and looked, an I can not for the life of me, find it.

Comment: Ok start over. In your terminal: 1. `cd ~ & mkdir -p src/race_res` 2. `cd src/race_res` 3. `touch race_results.py` 4. `mv ~/Desktop/Race_Results_Sample.txt ~/src/race_res` 5. Open `race_results.py` in a simple text editor (Atom, Sublime, BBEdit). 6. Paste the contents of your script above into that file. 7. `python -m race_results`  ///// Now you are working in a more basic fashion. Keep your files for this project in `~/src/race_res`. Make changes in a text editor. Execute via the command line. Plenty of time to learn Pycharm later.

Comment: If I wanted to use the absolute method, how would I need to word my code?

Comment: `with open("~/Desktop/Race_Results_Sample.txt", "r")`

Comment: `~` is a shortcut to the absolutely referenced directory `/Users/jess` i.e. your user's home. This is true, `~` will absolutely reference the User's home, on any unix variant system (like your Mac).

Comment: If you are learning Python tho I highly recommend not learning in Pycharm. I suggest having a look at this: https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex0.html

Comment: I am still getting the same error message in pycharm by using the absolute reference. I'm not sure how to use another text editor, I installed Sublime, but unsure how to execute my code in the application.

Comment: You can't execute your code in Sublime. It's just a text editor. Read the link in my last comment. You should modify your code in a text file using the editor, then execute the code using your Terminal. The comment that begins "Ok start over" tells you each command you need to run from your Terminal to do this.